# The usage of the word 'suspended' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of the word 'suspended' in this context?

> "Marseille are given a *suspended* one-point deduction and their fans
> are banned from travelling to away games until the end of the year."

[Source](https://theathletic.com/2993808/2021/12/03/french-football-crisis-missiles-thrown-fans-invading-pitch-matches-abandoned/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example, "suspended" means that the punishment in question will not be applied, provided that there is no more 'trouble' during the period noted, i.e. one year.

This is quite similar to being "on probation".

Comment: See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suspended_sentence)